# Return Timestamp With Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, timestamp

I have an auto generated timestamp that is created each time a record is inserted or updated in a mysql table. Is there a way to return this timestamp in a way similar to how I would use a keyholder to return a newly created id?

```
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

//Insert Contact
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_ADD, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, contact.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, contact.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, contact.getOrganizationId());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, contact.getType());
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, contact.getUserId());
        return preparedStatement;
        }   
}, keyHolder);
//Use keyholder to obtain newly created id
contact.setId(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());
```

Is there some way to also return the new timestamp without having to requery the table? I have been looking for ways to return it along with the id as a key in the keyholder, but it doesn't seem to be returned as a key?

Comment: In database how are you inserting records, trigger or procedure?

Comment: Please forgive my inexperience here, but i'm not sure of the difference. Trigger I think. The code above is actual production code that inserts a contact into the table.

Comment: The reason why I was asking is one idea of return value is if a procedure is being used then procedure could return values as `OUT` parameter and you could use from calling client. Of course there could be other ways.

Comment: MySQL has a [built-in feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) to set a column of type `TIMESTAMP` to the current timestamp when performing an insert/update.  My guess is that's how the timestamp is getting set here, rather than a trigger of some sort.

Comment: May I ask the reason why you do not want to query the table after insertion? The second query is virtually instant, so this is probably not a matter of performance, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few options for solving this issue on the MySQL database server side.  You could start with creating a `TRIGGER` on the table.  As `TRIGGER` has a restriction and cannot return data, you can set the `TIMESTAMP` value to a variable:

```
DEMILITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ai_tbl_name AFTER INSERT ON tbl_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

SET @TimeStamp = NEW.timestamp_column;

END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

To retrieve this timestamp value, run the following command:

```
SELECT @TimeStamp;
```

Since the variables are stored in the memory, there will be no need to open any tables again.

You go even further.  You could create a `STORED PROCEDURE` in MySQL to automate all the above (sample code, as I do not know your table's details):

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_procedure_name //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_procedure_name (IN col1_val VARCHAR(25),
                                    IN col2_val VARCHAR(25),
                                    IN col3_val INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES (col1_val, col2_val, col3_val);

    SELECT @TimeStamp;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

You can run this procedure with the following code:

```
CALL sp_procedure_name(col1_val, col2_val, col3_val);
```

As I'm not familiar with the Java, you'll need to finish it up with your side of code.

Answer (score 1):

Not very satisfying, but I think "no" is the answer to your question. I don't know any of the Spring stuff, but I think this is due to the basic JDBC that it's wrapping. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29

You only option would be to create a stored procedure on MySQL that has an out parameter and call that. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the variable `contact` is an instance for the newly inserted record. As it contains the newly generated `id` (primary key) field value, you can execute a new query to return the required `timestamp` field value for this new `id`.

The query may look like this:

```
select timestamp_field from my_table where id=?
```

Use `PreparedStatement` to input new `id` value and execute it to fetch required `timestamp` field value.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that this is how I have been retrieving the timestamp from the table and I wanted to know if there was a way to get the timestamp from the keyholder. I'm sorry, but I can't accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`GeneratedKeyHolder` also has two methods: `getKeyList()` that returns `Map<String,Object>` of generated fields; and `getKeyList()` that produces a list of generated keys for all affected rows.

See java doc of [GeneratedKeyHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/GeneratedKeyHolder.html) and [Spring tutorial of auto generated keys](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys)

In addition Spring's SimpleJdbcInsert has methods for generated key retrieval. See also method [SimpleJdbcInsert#usingGeneratedKeyColumns](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html#usingGeneratedKeyColumns%28java.lang.String...%29)

Comment: Based on the research you listed, a timestamp cannot be retrieved by the keyholder. Thank you for pointing that out. However, my question mentions that if its not possible with primary key that i'd need a way to retrieve the value without a second query. Knowing that its not possible with the keyholder, are there any ways from within the original query, maybe a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods in `java.sql.Connection` class causing PreparedStatement execution to return selected key columns :

```
PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql,
                                   int[] columnIndexes)
                                throws SQLException

PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql,
                                   String[] columnNames)
                                   throws SQLException
```

You don't need to use Spring KeyHolder & JDBCTemplate to do this.
The give hope you could number/name your timestamp column.  But the javadoc doesn't require or suggest that any JDBC implementation can return non-key columns, so your out of luck with this approach:

> *Creates a default PreparedStatement object capable of returning the auto-generated keys
>   designated by the given array. This array contains the names of the columns in the target
>   table that contain the auto-generated keys that should be returned.*

---

- As suggested in another answer, can switch to a stored procedure that does exactly what you want (CallableStatement is actually a PreparedStatement that executes storedprocedures - i.e. a subclass).
- Can populate the timestamp column within the prepared statement via new `Timestamp(new Date())` - but you should have in place a mechanism to sync times across your various servers (which is often used in windows and *nix environments).  Your trigger could set the timestamp only if a value wasn't already provided.

As part of your app & DB design, you need to commit to a philosophy of where certain operations occur.  If the DB derives needed data, the app needs to refresh data - you must pay the price of separate query executions or a combined stored proc that inserts & retrieves.