# Oracle - update record and return updated date in same query

Tags: java, oracle, sql-update, jdbctemplate

I'm using Java 8 with Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and Oracle 12.1,

I want to update record and get the exact time record was updated

```
jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_SQL, null);
```

Currently it returns (int) the number of rows affected, but I want the exact updated date

Must I send a new request to get current time which may be inaccurate?

More exact will be to save in column updated date, but then to execute another SQL

Is there another option to get updated date in one query?

Obviously, I don't want to use get date from code also (as `new Date()`) also because  server time is/can be different than DB Time

Comment: I think you can handle it on the server side itself, if update done; take current server time. I believe it may differ some milliseconds, however this is still feasible and acceptable.

Comment: @MohamedSweelam added a comment that I don't want this approach, also because server time is different than DB Time

Comment: If you do an `UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = systimestamp WHERE...` then you could run a query to retrieve that timestamp when the DB made the update.

Comment: @xtratic yes, I wrote it in my question, but I want 1 SQL

Comment: @user7294900 Example given in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decided to use JDBCTemplate most probably to simplify the code in comparison to *plain JDBC*.

This particular problem IMHO makes the *plain JDBC* solution as proposed in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58397775/4808122) much simpler, so I'd definitively recommend to get the database connection from JDBCTemplate and make the insert in a JDBC way.

The simplest solution using JDBCTemplate that comes to my mind is to wrap the insert in a `PROCEDURE` and return the timestamp as an `OUT` parameter.

Simple example (Adjust the time logik as required)

```
create procedure insert_with_return_time (p_str VARCHAR2, p_time OUT DATE) as
BEGIN 
   insert into identity_pk(pad) values(p_str);
   p_time := sysdate;
END;
/
```

The call is done using `SimpleJdbcCall`

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("insert_with_return_time");
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_str", str);
Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(params);
```

The `Map` contains the returned value e.g. `[P_TIME:2019-10-19 11:58:10.0]`

But I can only repeat, in this particular use case is IMHO *JDBC a rescue from JDBCTemplate*;)

Answer (score 1):

You're right that passing `new Date()` would store the server time rather than the DB time.

To store the DB time you can set your timestamp to the DB system timestamp `systimestamp` then you could run a query to retrieve that row and its updated timestamp.

If you want to update the row and get the updated timestamp in a single execution then you could do the following using `RETURNING INTO` where `TimestampUpdated` is your column name:

```
Connection con = ...;
String sql = "UPDATE TableName SET <updates> , TimestampUpdated = systimestamp RETURNING TimestampUpdated INTO ?";
CallableStatement statement = con.prepareCall(sql);
statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.TIMESTAMP);

int updateCount = statement.executeUpdate();
Timestamp timestampUpdated  = statement.getInt(1);
System.out.println("Timestamp Updated = " + timestampUpdated);
```

[Here is a related link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253476/2442526) doing this with JdbcTemplate

Comment: Thanks, I mention that I use Spring's `JdbcTemplate`

Comment: `returning into` can only be used inside a PL/SQL block, not with plain SQL

Comment: Thank you, I'll check tomorrow