# How To Fetch Updated Rows In JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to fetch all updated records after update operation (without running select query). There are many solutions which return number of rows of updated records but none of them satisfy my problem for oracle.

My code crashes on

```
emp.setBufferActSeq(rs.getLong("BUFFER_ACT_SEQ"));
```

because rs hasn't got any column named BUFFER_ACT_SEQ (actually rs has no column).

```
@Repository
public class BufferActRepositoryImpl {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public BufferActRepositoryImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public List<BufferActEntity> updateAndFetch() {
        String sqlQuery = "UPDATE BUFFER_ACT SET PNR = '2'";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new ResultSetExtractor<List<BufferActEntity>>() {

            public List<BufferActEntity> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

                List<BufferActEntity> resultList = new ArrayList<BufferActEntity>();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    BufferActEntity emp = new BufferActEntity();
                    emp.setBufferActSeq(rs.getLong("BUFFER_ACT_SEQ"));
                    resultList.add(emp);
                }

                return resultList;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I see you doing an update, but I don't see a fetch, which would require a select or the equivalent thereof.  Where in your method are you doing a select to generate a result set?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I want to reach updated rows without running a select query. Otherwise I could do it as you mentioned as

Comment: I asked similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58396930/oracle-update-record-and-return-updated-date-in-same-query

Comment: I am using oracle database